# Invoking a UNIX command in R - join operation

Tags: r, unix, system

```
system("join -o 1.2 <(sort new.txt) <(sort t.txt) > t20.txt;")

sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 0: `join -o 1.2 <(sort new.txt) <(sort t.txt) > t20.txt;'
```

How can I write this correctly?

Comment: You seem to have a quote problem. What should exactly be the command you want to launch from the command line?

Comment: I have just corrected the question. I want to invoke the join operation on a R terminal. It works on the bash terminal.

Comment: @nicola Any idea on the above mentioned?

Comment: I guess the problem comes from `system` using `sh` while your line needs `bash`. If you put your line in a file and then run `system("bash filename.sh")` it should work.

Comment: @nicola I am looking at appending this line with a R code so I was hoping to run it like this.

Answer (score 1):

As @nicola said, you can put the line into a file and run it as:

```
system("bash filename.sh")
```

If however you want to avoid creating the file, you can use the `-c` option on bash as follows:

```
system("bash -c 'join -o 1.2 <(sort new.txt) <(sort t.txt) > t20.txt'")
```

You can read more background on `-c` option in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34427146/whats-the-point-of-eval-bash-c-as-opposed-to-just-evaluating-a-variable).