# Can't use redirections in a shell command stored in a string

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I have the following code in Jenkins "Execute shell"

```
command="curl -H \"X-HockeyAppToken:${!HOCKEYAPP_TARGET_TOKEN}\" ${HOCKEYAPP_SERVER_API}/apps/${!HOCKEYAPP_TARGET_ID}/app_versions?include_build_urls=true 2>/dev/null"
echo "$command"
test=$($command)
```

The echo prints something like:

```
curl -H "X-HockeyAppToken: 1234567890abcdef1234567890abc" https://hockeyapp.example.com/api/2/apps/ccc1234567890abcdef1234567890/app_versions?include_build_urls=true 2>/dev/null
```

If I copy the curl command line into the shell, it works fine.

However, I get the following error in Jenkins:

```
curl -H "X-HockeyAppToken: 1234567890abcdef1234567890abc" https://hockeyapp.example.com/api/2/apps/ccc1234567890abcdef1234567890/app_versions?include_build_urls=true 2>/dev/null: No such file or directory
```

Where is that "2>/dev/null: No such file or directory" is coming and why is that interpreted that way?

Comment: See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). Strings shouldn't be used to store commands; use an array or a function instead. See also the question this is closed as duplicative of, for a detailed explanation of the mechanism (and thus the "why") in the accepted answer: [What's the point of eval/bash -c as opposed to just evaluating a variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34427146/whats-the-point-of-eval-bash-c-as-opposed-to-just-evaluating-a-variable)

Comment: (Also, comparing `echo "$foo"` to the output of parsing and running the command stored in the variable named `foo` is misleading, because it confuses the critical distinction between literal and syntactic quotes: For `echo` to print a quote that quote must be literal, but for the shell to treat a quote as a directive for its use, it must be syntactic; consequently, in a great many cases, something that causes `echo` to emit a useful command on output *will never* behave as a useful command itself).

Comment: Instead of putting `echo` in front of a command if you want to see what it would do, consider instead `printf '%q ' your-command "$here"; "${with_arguments[@]}"; echo` -- that way what's printed can be copied-and-pasted to have the same effect as running `your-command "$here" "${with_arguments[@]}"` would, which is **not** the case with `echo your-command "$here" "${with_arguments[@]}"`.